# How to add a region specific Locale to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

I am trying to add a US region specific locale to rails, however tells me that `:en_locale` is not a valid code for a locale. How can I include this specific region?

In `app/config/locales`, I have `en.yml` and `en-US.yml`.

My `application.rb`, I have the following:

```
# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
# config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :'en-US']
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]
# config.i18n.fallbacks = {:'zh-MY' => :'zh-CN'} # If we want to designate a lang to fallback to
```

Error Message:

```
I18n::InvalidLocale - :en_us is not a valid locale:
  i18n (0.6.9) lib/i18n.rb:288:in `enforce_available_locales!'
  i18n (0.6.9) lib/i18n/config.rb:11:in `locale='
  actionview (4.1.14.2) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:239:in `locale='
  actionview (4.1.14.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:19:in `locale='
  i18n (0.6.9) lib/i18n.rb:35:in `locale='
```

Answer (score 0):

> The i18n library takes a pragmatic approach to locale keys (after some
>   discussion), including only the locale ("language") part, like :en,
>   :pl, not the region part, like :en-US or :en-GB, which are
>   traditionally used for separating "languages" and "regional setting"
>   or "dialects". Many international applications use only the "language"
>   element of a locale such as :cs, :th or :es (for Czech, Thai and
>   Spanish). However, there are also regional differences within
>   different language groups that may be important. For instance, in the
>   :en-US locale you would have $ as a currency symbol, while in :en-GB,
>   you would have £. Nothing stops you from separating regional and other
>   settings in this way: you just have to provide full "English - United
>   Kingdom" locale in a :en-GB dictionary. Few gems such as [Globalize3](https://github.com/globalize/globalize)
>   may help you implement it.

~Rails Guides